Extracting a substring in SQL without knowing the position
I have a column called VALUE, that contains data like this.
00002824/04456/0009639/6410/00001/00001/COL/07/00001/001/0052/01/06/0090139177/WHTG_/000000000000419138

I need to extract the data after the 9th "/" always, so in this example, I'd like to retrieve only 0052/01/06/0090139177/WHTG_/000000000000419138.
I've been trying to use the SUBSTRING function, but it doesnt seem to work. Can I get some help please?
SELECT SUBSTRING(S.SCOPE, 
              CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, 
              CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, 
              CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, 
              CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE, 
              CHARINDEX('/', S.SCOPE) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1 + 1,
              LEN(S.SCOPE))
FROM S.SCOPE


@AaronBertrand Its Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

It's better to do this while storing the data or on the client. This isn't easy, even with a regular expression- check this question that asks how to match after the Nth occurrence of a character. Azure SQL announced a private preview of regular expressions in March 2024 but I don't thing they've said anything since

@PanagiotisKanavos What's wrong with STRING_SPLIT() in this case (or OPENJSON() in older versions)? I don't disagree that if that portion of the data is important it should be stored separately, but often folks are just having to deal with something beyond their control.

Both generate rows that need to be gathered back into single values. The code becomes very complex, especially if other fields have to be extracted as well. Should something go wrong, debugging the complex queries will be a real pain.

@PanagiotisKanavos YMMV. I find string_split/agg a lot more intuitive and straightforward for this task than openjson() or xml approaches.

In Azure SQL Database (or SQL Server 2022 or newer), you can use the enable_ordinal parameter to STRING_SPLIT(), and then re-assamble in the right order using STRING_AGG():
SELECT t.Id, STRING_AGG(s.value, '/')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.ordinal)
  FROM dbo.things AS t
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.value, '/', 1) AS s
 WHERE s.ordinal > 9 /* or 10? */
 GROUP BY t.Id;


Example db<>fiddle

If you're on SQL Server 2017 or 2019, you can use OPENJSON(), e.g.:
SELECT t.Id, STRING_AGG(j.value, '/')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j.[key]))
  FROM dbo.things AS t
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(t.value, '/', '","') + '"]') AS j
 WHERE j.[key] >= 9 /* or 10? */
 GROUP BY t.Id;


Example db<>fiddle

But I find it more tedious because:

You're shoe-horning an existing string to make it adhere to JSON format
It's problematic if your string can contain special characters, like '"'
JSON's key is 0-based, so you have to think in off-by-one terms
Also, key is a string, so you need to convert to get it to order like a number
you still need STRING_AGG() for simple reassembly; to me, STRING_SPLIT() just seems a more natural companion

I'm confused about what you seem to mean by "9th" so if you really mean 10th then just change > 9 or >= 9 to > 10 or >= 10.

Thanks, @Aaron. I need to retrieve the entire string that follows after the 9th "/", meaning this part from my initial example - 0052/01/06/0090139177/WHTG_/000000000000419138

@Newbie I see, but after the 9th starts with 001/0052, no?
